# how to differentiate a single letter in html5 button

Tags: html, button

I need to differentiate the single letter as italic font in html button value? can you please guide me?

I need the button Text as

Hello *W*orld

W is in italic style

I have used
"Hello World"

Comment: Have you tried putting the w inside its own span and styling the span?

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
<button type="button">Hello <i>W</i>orld</button>
```

Perhaps it is slightly better (but more verbose) to use styles:

```
<button type="button">Hello <i class="italic">W</i>orld</button>

<style>
    em.italic { font-style: italic; }
</style>
```

Comment: is there a reason for <button type="button"> ? Wouldnt be <button> enaugh?

Comment: @Max the default for a button is `submit`, that will send data to the server unless you prevent it. We do not know what Ramya want here so I guess that is why people left it out. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/button

Comment: Why use an em instead of a span and then styling it? Are we not trying to separate structure and design?

Comment: We don’t know whether it’s meant to be a submit button either, so discussing the `type` attribute is outside the scope of the question.

Comment: @JukkaK.Korpela: I use `type` on the button out of habit and for the reason given by @AllanKimmerJensen. @TheWaxMann: I use `em` because the `W` is indeed emphasized and because [it is recommended](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/i) over `i`. I agree that using styles would be a good addition to the answer. I will go ahead and add that as second option.

Comment: Regarding the markup used for italic, the question says “differentiate”, not “emphasize”. Actually, “differentiate” sounds very much like the thing that the `i` element is supposed to do according to HTML5 drafts.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the the `::first-letter` CSS pseudo-element.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::first-letter

Could end up something like this:

```
button span::first-letter {
   font-style: italic;
}
```

And the HTML like this.

```
<button>
   Hello <span>World</span>
</button>
```

You could add a class to the span and rewrite the css rule accordingly, would be a little more safe, as you could get some unwanted results like this.

You can also just do `<button>Hello <em>W</em>orld</button>`.

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS `::first-letter` like this.

```
<p>This is a text</p> 

<style>
  p::first-letter{
    color:red;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button><i>W</i>orld</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<button><em>W</em>orld</button>
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wkerswell/9baAG/)

Answer (score 0):

if you use a button tag, you can simply do that:

```
<button>
    Hello <em>W</em>orld
</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use the oldschool HTML `<em>` tag.

```
<button><em>W</em>orld</button>
```

[Heres a Fiddle.](http://jsfiddle.net/w9FAh/)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways to do this, but the simplest and most robust is to use the `<button>` element and `i` markup inside it:

```
<button>Hello <i>W</i>orld</button>
```

You can use any text-level (phrase-level) markup inside a `button` element.

However, it is typographically not appropriate to italicize just one letter in a word. However, the same technical approach applies to methods that may really differentiate, like bolding (`b` element) or color.